# How to return all rows that contain specific value in cell from datatable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, rows

I want to return all the rows that contains a specific string to a textbox.
I tried a lot of things but didn't get the result i was looking for.

```
foreach(DataRowView drTesla in dgdArtikel.ItemsSource)
                {
                    if (dgdArtikel.Items.Contains("Tesla"))
                    {
                        // do something
                    }
                }
```

Description of image, overview datatable and the wanted result

[image: 1]

Comment: Do you need to return the entire row or the specific field only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am pretty sure your datagrid view has rows of concrete type which you forgot to mention the correct way to do what you need is:

```
dgdArtikel.ItemsSource.Cast<Artikel>().Where(i => i.Code == "Tesla")
```